# Store jQuery Code for Later use with $(window).resize()

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery content slider where each slide is the full width of the screen. I am calculating the width that each slide should be in jQuery - not CSS (I have my reasons for doing so - I won't bother boring you with them).
As you can see from the code below, I am calculating all the dimensions twice - the second time is for when the user resizes the window. I am just wondering if it is possible for me to store the code and then just call on that inside the $(window).resize(); ?
This should have a simple answer, but it is eluding me at the moment!

```
var windowHeight = $(window).height(); //Get the height of the window
var windowWidth = $(window).width(); //Get the width of the window
$(".slide").css("width",windowWidth + "px").css("height",windowHeight + "px"); //Make each slide’s dimensions equal to that of the window

$(".slide").each(function(i, e) {
    //Execute animation
    $("#trigger" + i).click(function(e) {
        $(".slideContainer").stop(true, false).animate({top:-windowHeight * rowIndex + "px" ,left:-windowWidth * slideIndex + "px"},900,'easeInOutExpo'); //The variables here that I use to animate the slide are unimportant to my question. I’ve removed the vars so this code is easier to read.
    });
});

//Resize
$(window).resize(function() {
    var windowHeight = $(window).height(); 
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    $(".slide").css("width",windowWidth + "px").css("height",windowHeight + "px");

    $(".slide").each(function(i, e) {
        $("#trigger" + i).click(function(e) {
            $(".slideContainer").stop(true, false).animate({top:-windowHeight * rowIndex + "px" ,left:-windowWidth * slideIndex + "px"},900,'easeInOutExpo');
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function adjustSize(){
    var windowHeight = $(window).height(); //Get the height of the window
    var windowWidth = $(window).width(); //Get the width of the window
    $(".slide").css("width",windowWidth + "px").css("height",windowHeight + "px"); //Make each slide’s dimensions equal to that of the window

    $(".slide").each(function(i, e) {
        //Execute animation
        $("#trigger" + i).click(function(e) {
            $(".slideContainer").stop(true, false).animate({top:-windowHeight * rowIndex + "px" ,left:-windowWidth * slideIndex + "px"},900,'easeInOutExpo'); //The variables here that I use to animate the slide are unimportant to my question. I’ve removed the vars so this code is easier to read.
        });
    });
}
$(window).resize(adjustSize);
adjustSize();  //or $(window).resize(adjustSize).resize(), it works too
```

Comment: Except, you don't want to reinstall the click handlers on every resize event.

Comment: @jfriend00 That's what the original code does. We weren't asked to critique his code, just show how to get rid of the redundancy. Putting it into a function is the answer.

Comment: IMO, good answers shouldn't contain obviously wrong code.  You know how to fix it.  Why don't you?  A good answer should be correct code.

Comment: Also, we can get rid of `.each()` and can cache `$(window)`

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to create a function and call it once during initialization and then when the window resizes.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //don't need to attach the click handlers everytime... just do it once
    $(".slide").each(function(i, e) {
        //Execute animation
        $("#trigger" + i).click(function(e) {
            $(".slideContainer").stop(true, false).animate({top:-windowHeight * rowIndex + "px" ,left:-windowWidth * slideIndex + "px"},900,'easeInOutExpo'); 
         });
     });

     adjustSize();
})

$(window).resize(adjustSize);

function adjustSize(){
    var windowHeight = $(window).height(); //Get the height of the window
    var windowWidth = $(window).width(); //Get the width of the window
    $(".slide").css("width",windowWidth + "px").css("height",windowHeight + "px"); //Make each slide’s dimensions equal to that of the window
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works all for one thing - when I click on the trigger, the slide animates too far. It is still using the original values before window resize. The slides' dimensions do update though. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you really need (and it should work):

```
$(function() {
    var $window = $(window),
        windowHeight, 
        windowWidth;
    $(".slide").each(function(i, e) {
        $("#trigger" + i).on("click", function(e) {
            $(".slideContainer")
                .stop(true, false)
                .animate({top:-windowHeight * rowIndex + "px" ,left:-windowWidth * slideIndex + "px"},900,'easeInOutExpo'); 
        });
    });
    function adjustSize(){
        windowHeight = $window.height();
        windowWidth = $window.width();
        //Make each slide’s dimensions equal to that of the window
        $(".slide").css({ width: windowWidth, height: windowHeight });
    }

    $window.resize(adjustSize);
    adjustSize();
})
```